# The data returned from a result is repeated several times - ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, typescript

The getCourseAndModuleInfo function, returns some data from the database and stores it in states.

For some reason all the information is being repeated several times, as an example I used the course_id.

I realized that it has to do with the queries I make in the API and also with useEffect, however, I did not understand why this is happening.

I would like to know why this is happening, can you help me?

```
import React, { useState, useCallback, useEffect } from 'react';
import api from '../../services/api';

interface CourseInfo {
  course_id: string;
  module_id: string;
}

interface HeaderInfoProps {
  course_info: CourseInfo;
}

const HeaderInfo: React.FC<HeaderInfoProps> = course_info => {
  const [isLoadingCourseName, setIsLoadingCourseName] = useState(false);
  const [isLoadingModuleName, setIsLoadingModuleName] = useState(false);
  const [courseName, setCourseName] = useState({ name: '' });
  const [moduleName, setModuleName] = useState({ name: '' });

  const { course_id, module_id } = course_info.course_info;

  // This is repeating several times
  console.log(course_id);

  const getCourseAndModuleInfo = useCallback(async () => {
    try {
      setIsLoadingCourseName(true);
      setIsLoadingModuleName(true);
      await api.get(`/course_name/${course_id}`).then(response => {
        const course_name = response.data;
        setCourseName(course_name);
      });

      await api.get(`/module_name/${module_id}`).then(response => {
        const module_name = response.data;
        setModuleName(module_name);
      });
      setIsLoadingCourseName(false);
      setIsLoadingModuleName(false);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }, [course_id, module_id]);

  useEffect(() => {
    getCourseAndModuleInfo();
  }, [getCourseAndModuleInfo]);

  return (
    ...
  );
};

export default HeaderInfo;
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. The component will render as many times as "necessary". At a *minimum* this would be 2x. Your callback sets multiple states, which depending on timing could cause multiple renders. Is there an actual *problem*, or are you just trying to understand functional component behavior?

Comment: So this is normal behavior? For example, console.log is printing 8.